# Vmstat seems to give non-standard values?

Tags: unix, performance-monitoring, vmstat, diagnostic, tru64

We have a proprietry system, which runs on Tru64 Unix.
It is a terminal based system.
We are able to use the login 'vmstat' to the system which brings up a vmstat-like view.
However, the information displayed is slightly different from the standard vmstat.

```
10:27  up 36 days, 20:18,  797 users,  load average: 15.75, 15.52, 14.94
Virtual Memory Statistics: (pagesize = 8192)
  procs      memory        pages                            intr        cpu
  r   w   u  act free wire fault  cow zero react  pin pout  in   sy  cs us sy id
 27  2K 335   9M 129K 874K  105G 581M   9G  135M   1G  13M  2K 125K 13K 23 11 66
 33  2K 336   9M 131K 874K  114K 4331  59K  3362 9729  334  2K 156K 15K 33 11 56
 26  2K 333   9M 130K 873K 89798 2147  50K   157 5481   60  2K 128K 14K 30  8 62
 34  2K 332   9M 121K 873K 86165 2474  40K  4107 5709   71  2K 220K 14K 35 12 53
 28  2K 328   9M 139K 873K 99686 3071  43K  7362 7029  140  2K 177K 14K 38 11 51
```

The 'r' for processes is part of the standard vmstat layout, but not 'w' or 'u'.
I cannot find any references to this kind of vmstat layout on google.
According to [linuxcommand.org](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/vmstat8.html) I should get the layout:

```
r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si  so    bi    bo   in    cs us sy id wa
```

instead of:

```
r   w   u  act free wire fault  cow zero react  pin pout  in   sy  cs us sy id
```

Is anybody able to shed any light as to why mine is different? Or at least what each of the fields mean?

Answer (score 1):

Yours is different because you're running [Tru64](http://forums11.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447626+1247536016017+28353475&threadId=432207), and not linux.

(most 'standard' unix programs will differ slightly in their options and output depending on their source - gnu/bsd/sun/etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, after a lot of digging I found the documentation for Tru64 vmstat on HP's site.
Google seemed to fail me on this occasion.

[True64 VMStat documentation](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V51_HTML/MAN/MAN1/0420____.HTM?jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN)